# Infinite-Loop GoogleAppScript

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

How can i create an infinite loop that changes a cell value repeatedly in Google-app-script?

```
function doTest() {    
    if(x>=360) x = 0;
  Utilities.sleep(500);
      x = x+1;   
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a13').setValue(x);  
  incr();
}
```

I would like it to increment a cell value until it reaches 360 and then start from 0.

Comment: Use a `for-loop` or a `while` loop. In any case, note that there are quotas on script run time and the function won't run till the end of time.

Comment: Yeah, it will stop after around 5 minutes, and it wouldn't be predictable.

Comment: I apologize my answer was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following do the job !
Note the call to `flush`, this ensures the spreadsheet will be refreshed at each iteration.
Otherwise you won't see the cell update in realtime.
Enjoy ;-)

```
function doIncrease() {
  for(var x=0;;x++){
    //Set value
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a13').setValue(x);
    //Flush changes to spreadsheet
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    //Wait as long as desired
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    //Reboot the Endless loop from 0 to 360
    if(x==360) x=0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An infinite loop will eventually crash your app. But assuming that's what you're going for, here's one way to do it:

```
function iterate() {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a13');
    var i = 0;

    while(true) {
        range.setValue(i);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        i = (++i) % 361; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your loop process in my answer, because I thought that it is excellent way. Thank you for making me study from your answer. But if you have any issues for this, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to count up the value of number of cell "A13" on the active Spreadsheet every 0.5 seconds.
- You want to loop the number from 0 to 360.
- You want to loop this cycle as the infinite loop.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them. In this sample script, I used a sidebar. Namely, I used Javascript and Google Apps Script. I thought that the infinite loop might be able to be achieved by running Google Apps Script from the sidebar. I could confirm that in my environment, this count could be run more than the maximum execution time of 6 minutes of Google Apps Script.

#### Usage:

When you use this script, please do the following flow.

1. Copy and paste the following script to the script editor (the container-bound script of Spreadsheet).
2. Run the function of `run()`.

   - By this, a sidebar is opened on the Spreadsheet.
3. When you click a button of "start", the number is put to the cell "A13" of the active sheet, and the value is counted up every 0.5 seconds. The number loops the cycle from 0 to 360.

   - If you want to stop the count, please click "stop" button.

#### Sample script:

```
function setValue(v) {
  Utilities.sleep(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A13").setValue(v);
}

function run() {
  var str = '<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()"><input type="button" id="stop" value="stop" onclick="stop=false"><script>var stop=false; function work(v){return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(()=> resolve()).setValue(v));}async function start(){stop=true; var i=0; while(stop){await work(i); i=(++i) % 361;}}</script>';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Expanded HTML:

At above sample script, HTML is minified. Below script is the expanded HTML.

**This is only for confirming HTML. So you are not required to copy and paste this.**

```
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
<input type="button" id="stop" value="stop" onclick="stop=false">

<script>
  var stop = false;

  function work(v) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => resolve()).setValue(v));
  }

  async function start() {
    stop = true;
    var i = 0;
    while(stop) {
      await work(i);
      i = (++i) % 361;  // This is from Dimu Designs's answer.
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### Note:

- I used the loop process by [Dimu Designs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56229546).

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

If this method was not the direction of your goal, I apologize.